# Visual Studio built in database vs SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Are there any differences between the built-in database in visual studio and an external database like sql server or oracle? Which one is more used and reliable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition.aspx

> LocalDB is created specifically for developers. It is very easy to
>   install and requires no management, yet it offers the same T-SQL
>   language, programming surface and client-side providers as the regular
>   SQL Server Express. In effect the developers that target SQL Server no
>   longer have to install and manage a full instance of SQL Server
>   Express on their laptops and other development machines.

Comment: what about performance etc